# Keep form files after validation error

Tags: html, forms, multipartform-data

I have a form where I simultaneously send several (let's say 10) files to the backend, along with some other regular input fields.

When I find a validation problem in the backend I display the form again and fill the regular inputs (dropdowns, text inputs, etc.), but I cannot fill the file fields, forcing the user to select the files from the file directory again.

The solution I think of is sending the base64 encoded representation of the files, and put them back in the form in case there is a validation error, but I would like to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Needs much, much more information. This question is not answerable in the current format

Comment: for a start what technology backend are you using? Show some code or something?

Comment: answer is: Upload regardless of submit.... attach a batch number to the files... then when validation fails they don't need to re-select the files as they are already upload... the only part that needs to be fixed is the validation. attach a timeout to rogue files... which never passed validation to be deleted from sever after x time. for browser security reasons.. you will not be able to achieve what you want...this is the next best thing. Hope  you follow what i mean.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for your answer. This question is not language-dependent, I mean, the same problem can be faced with different backend technologies without making any difference in the question.

Comment: Not sure if there are way to preset file upload input field, and I am interested in the answer too, but one possible workaround is to submit the form through AJAX so that the file input will still be there. (And redirect on successful submit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what you do, you can not skip server-side validation. For security reasons (someone sending raw requests for example). As far as showing the files in case of error (or simple reloading) I would send it as Base64, but via AJAX if the files are large.

1. **Client-side validation**: most validations (if not all) can be done using plain JS. Be it filesize, content type... and more specific validations according to filetypes (image, document...)
2. **Server-side validation**: Once sent, fully validate the file and content.
3. **Send files back**:In case of error, send the files with the request if small. If big send them via AJAX to avoid blocking and keep page loading times fast.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest  thing to do would be :

1) Validate all fields on the client side (javascript/jquery)

2) Once all other inputs are validated, then you send in Files.

NB: If you need to validate some values on the server side, use ajax for both steps (1) and (2). Also, try to give a bit more details to get  quality answers

Comment: Performing the validation and the submission in two different HTTP call voids the validation, as the parameters sent in the second request can be different from the parameters sent in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary store for uploaded files and would send back only a unique-hard-to-guess ID got from the store instead than the whole file.

The form section for a single file upload would then include also an hidden input carrying the unique file-ID.

When processing the request: if there is a file in the request get the file (and store it if form not valid) otherwise if there is a file-ID get the file from store.